# Get unique records from list without affecting the actual order of list

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to fetch distinct records from a list. My code is fetching distinct records but it is changing the order of list. How can I get records without affecting order of data.

I am using this code

```
var data= data1.GroupBy(x => x.CourseId).Select(g => g.First());
```

or

```
var data = data1.GroupBy(c => new { CourseId = c.CourseId, CourseName = c.CourseName })
                .Select(c => new { CourseId = c.Key.CourseId, CourseName = c.Key.CourseName });
```

Both queries giving same order of output

Please help!
Thanks!
Deepika

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Can you give an example?

Comment: What do you mean by `get records without affecting order of data`? Unless you specify `OrderBy` there is no granted default order.

Comment: whatever order is coming in data1, i need the records in same order, but the code i am using changing the order or recs

Answer (score 2):

You should use `distinct()` and an `EqualityComparer`.

```
class CourseDetails
{
    public CourseDetails(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }
    public int Id { get; }
}

class CourseDetailsEqualityComparer : EqualityComparer<CourseDetails>
{
    public override bool Equals(CourseDetails x, CourseDetails y)
    {
        return x.Id == y.Id;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(CourseDetails obj)
    {
        return obj.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void FindDistinct()
{
    var courses = new List<CourseDetails> { 
        new CourseDetails(4),
        new CourseDetails(2),
        new CourseDetails(3),
        new CourseDetails(2),
        new CourseDetails(3),
        new CourseDetails(1),
        new CourseDetails(1),
    };

    var expected = new List<CourseDetails> {
        new CourseDetails(4),
        new CourseDetails(2),
        new CourseDetails(3),
        new CourseDetails(1),
    };

    var distinct = courses.Distinct(new CourseDetailsEqualityComparer()).ToList();

    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, distinct, new CourseDetailsComparer());
}

class CourseDetailsComparer : Comparer<CourseDetails>
{
    public override int Compare(CourseDetails x, CourseDetails y)
    {
        return x.Id.CompareTo(y.Id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% it will answer your question but you can try ".Distinct()" function in C#.

var data= data1.Distinct();
or
var data= data1.Distinct(x => x.CourseId);

Comment: [`Distinct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.100).aspx) isn't *guaranteed* to return items in the same order as they originally appear, but some [evidence suggests](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/12/30/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-14-distinct/) that it's the only natural way to implement it.

Comment: `Distinct` cannot take a lamba/property as a parameter. One needs to use an EqualityComparer . [Enumerable.Distinct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Add a new line of code:

```
data  = (from o in data order by o.sortproperty Ascending).toList();
```

Comment: This is not helpful. The question clearly states 'without affecting the actual order'

Answer (score 0):

You can try this tested code. It gives a list of distinct items without changing the original order.

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List <Person> P_list = new List<Person>();
            P_list.Add(new Person("Jack", "Harvey", "Smyrna, GA 30080"));
            P_list.Add(new Person("Tyler", "Marsden", "Iowa City, IA 52240"));
            P_list.Add(new Person("Callum", "Richardson ", "Marquette, MI 49855"));
            P_list.Add(new Person("Taylor", "Craig ", "Logan, UT 84321"));
            P_list.Add(new Person("Callum", "Richardson ", "Marquette, MI 49855"));
            P_list.Add(new Person("Tyler", "Marsden", "Iowa City, IA 52240"));
            P_list.Add(new Person("William", "Donnelly", "Richmond, IN 47374"));
            P_list.Add(new Person("Callum", "Richardson ", "Marquette, MI 49855"));
            P_list.Add(new Person("Jack", "Harvey", "Smyrna, GA 30080"));
            P_list.Add(new Person("Billy", "Reid ", "New York, NY 10029"));            

            IEnumerable<Person> distinct = P_list.Distinct(new PersonComparer());
            foreach (var item in distinct)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", item.FName,item.LName,item.Location);
            }
            Console.Read();
        }

    }

    class Person
    {
        public string FName { get; set; }
        public string LName { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public Person(string f, string l, string loc)
        {
            FName = f;
            LName = l;
            Location = loc;
        }
    }

    public class PersonComparer : IEqualityComparer<Person>
    {
        bool IEqualityComparer<Person>.Equals(Person x, Person y)
        {
            return (x.FName == y.FName & x.LName == y.LName && x.Location == y.Location);
        }

        int IEqualityComparer<Person>.GetHashCode(Person obj)
        {
            string person = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", obj.FName, obj.LName, obj.Location);
            return person.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This will not work if one tries it with a class (OP has objects with a CourseId property) `Distinct` will see each of the objects as unique unless overrides the `Equals` method for the class